# Find Sankhara and Dhamma in the following sentence?

Tags: dhammas, sankhara

Because there are several meanings of sanskharas and Dhamma, I am unable to exactly pin point when and what I should identify as sanskharas and when I should identify Dhamma.

Please help me identify sanskharas and Dhamma in the following sentence:

Max ate ice cream hurriedly and found it cold and sweet. He loved the taste of ice cream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Max = sankhara (mental formation/view)
- ate = sankhara (an action that requires various causal factors) + dhamma (duty of living) + sankhara (intentional mental formation)
- ice cream = sankhara (conditioned phenomena) + dhamma (natural phenomena)
- hurriedly = sankhara (intentional mental formation) plus sankhara (conditioned by ignorance) plus dhamma (mode of living)
- found = sankhara (mental formation of view/idea) + dhamma (mentality)
- cold and sweet = sankhara (conditioned phenomena) + sankhara (view & opinion mental formation) plus dhamma (natural phenomena)
- He = (mental formation/view)
- loved = ((mental formation of defilement)
- taste = Dhamma (natural phenomena) + sankhara (conditioned phenomena from tongue, flavour + tongue consciousness)
- ice cream = dhamma (natural phenomena) + sankhara (conditioned phenomena made from milk, sugar, flavour, tools, etc) + sankhara (mental formation of name/label).